# Geo Id in sql query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to show date and time according to visitor's Region the date and time stored in database. I wrote a code there is an error in query

Here is my code:

```
        RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo("US");
        int geo_id = region.GeoId;
```

Query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), upload_time, " + geo_id + ") AS upload_time FROM table1
```

Error:

```
244 is not a valid style number when converting from datetime to a character string.
```

Comment: what do you get in geo_id? Also what is value of upload_time?

Comment: @Kalsoom geo_id is geographical id not a sql datetime format code, so its giving error.

Comment: So you need to append upload time and geo_id??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your '`geo_id`' is working as '`style`' part in casting datetime part.

Syntax for CONVERT:

`CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )`

Now your '`geo_id`' value (i guess it is 244) exceeds the maximum range of styling.

I guess that's why you query returning error message.

Thank you.